# CKAN Docker container not running

Tags: docker, ckan

I am running the example [installation using docker](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-using-docker.html) container from the CKAN site.  A clean run, that downloads fresh (no local images) gives no errors

```
docker run -d --name db ckan/postgresql         
docker run -d --name solr ckan/solr     
docker run -d -p 80:80 --link db:db --link solr:solr ckan/ckan
```

but then a "docker ps" does not have the ckan image running ...

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
90c6e6a77b0a        ckan/solr:latest         "java -jar start.jar   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       8983/tcp            solr                
53f9a9f5c145        ckan/postgresql:latest   "/usr/local/bin/run"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       5432/tcp            db
```

Where would errors show?

Answer (score 2):

`docker ps` only lists running containers. You have to pass in the `-a` option in order to list all containers you have run

```
docker ps -a
```

Find the right container and run the following command to see any error messages it may have reported before shutting down

```
docker logs <container_id>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like the solr container is not the correct version
    File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/__init__.py", line 306, in check_solr_schema_version    
    % (version, ', '.join(SUPPORTED_SCHEMA_VERSIONS)))
ckan.lib.search.common.SearchError: SOLR schema version not supported: 2.0. Supported versions are [2.3]
*** /etc/my_init.d/70_initdb failed with status 1

Comment: did you find a resolution for this? I have the same problem on a Google docker install

Answer (score 1):

As at March 6 2015 described at https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/2255

ensure that you have killed off any solr containers still running using

```
    docker rm <idnumber>
```

then use the more recent schema config

```
  wget https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/config/solr/schema.xml

  docker run -d --name solr -v `pwd`/schema.xml:/opt/solr/example/solr/ckan/conf/schema.xml ckan/solr
```

then repeat the original failing step:

```
    docker run -d -p 80:80 --link db:db --link solr:solr ckan/ckan
```

-- EDIT -- This looks like it works but it introduces other problems. 
Am going to experiment with suggestion to use https://github.com/datacats/datacats